# Possible to get more than 20K+ triangles at 35fps on iPhone 3GS?

Tags: iphone, performance, iphone-3gs

I'm programming a new engine for iOS and I'm at a point where I can test how much power I can get out of my engine.

My code is written in C++ and the engine is written in a highly efficient manner to do streaming, batch rendering, frustum culling, occlusion culling, fast memory managers, etc. However, the results don't satisfy my expectations and I'm wondering if anyone has been able to get more out of their iPhone device.

Right now I'm rendering only the geometry with textures and the best I get is about 20K+ triangles being rendered at ~35fps on my iPhone 3GS.

Is this somehow the maximum iPhone 3GS can do? Or has anyone done better?

P.S. I'm doing no triangle strips yet, so i know there is about ~5fps improvement in there.

Comment: The world's a pretty amazing place when we're concerned with only getting 20K triangles per frame at 35fps on our cell phones.

Comment: lol, I know 20k is already a lot. but i'm trying to write a 3D renderer that can compete with the best renderer on the market :p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as knowing the maximum possible performance of the 3GS take a look here:
http://www.glbenchmark.com/phonedetails.jsp?benchmark=glpro11&D=Apple%20iPhone%203G%20S&testgroup=lowlevel

Comment: thanks, it seems iphone 3GS can't do any faster than this then, the guy doing the benchmark has the same fps with only 6k triangles.

Comment: I think you may be interpreting that data incorrectly, that is 6000 kTriangles or 6000 x 1000.  I have also read elsewhere that the 3GS can do about 7 Million triangles/sec.  I am not sure how that translates into what you are testing though.

Answer (score 0):

well, i did more research on this. i was already aware of 7M t/s but that's just a number not taking triangle filling in account.

so to make sure there wasn't a big bottleneck in my code i downloaded the Oolong engine and did some comparison and the speed was fairly the same.

(core animation results)
Oolong engine(running the San Angeles demo):
5k to 14k @~60
20k to 25k @~40
25k to 30k @~30

I'm getting very much the same results in terms of speed.